# Best way to cover up the vents on a headlight that leak?

Tags: headlight

My aftermarket headlights that I just purchased have had problems with condensation for some time now.  All the rubber covers around where the bulbs are place are sealed tight and installed correctly.  I did notice the small "vents" which were covered with what looks like some sort of venting patch.  Its just a piece of fabric and seems to not be the tightest seal.  What would be the best way to re-patch these vents with something more water-tight?

For reference I have a 2001 Impala.

Answer (score 5):

There are two designs vented and non-vented. In the vented design the vents actually help prevent the condensation. Make sure they are clear, you may even have to add additional holes to create more venting.

[See this article for more information](http://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/how-to/repair-questions/how-to-prevent-foggy-headlights)

Answer (score 0):

I have a chevy with the same fabric.  I suspect it is Gore-Tex/PFTE material.  It allows condensation to escape.  But does not let in water drops.  A breathable membrane seems ideal.  This is a guess. I am buying a sample of Gore-Tex and will cut and glue around the hole in my headlights to hopefully stop fogging.  Gore-Tex fabric's properties of breathing does not last forever.  My chevy is 12 years old.